# Enable/disable checkbox depended on the given value in an EditText

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext, android-checkbox

I have an EditText and a CheckBox. The EditText has an inputStyle numbers only. When entering a value of 0 in the EditText, I'd like that the CheckBox becomes disabled. But if the entered value is greater than 0, then the CheckBox should be enabled.
The checks should be done on the fly, so while typing and after every character input the check should be done. 
I came across `afterTextChanged`, but I can't get it to work, can someone help me out here?

```
public class AddBuilding extends Activity implements TextWatcher {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.building);

       myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString()) < 0)
                myCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            else
                myCheckBox.setEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: It must work. Do you get any erros? In your code I didn't see where you're using findViewById methos to fill the myEditText var. So it must be null.

Comment: Yeah When opening my Activity, that already gives me a null pointer exception, but before I added the ` myEditText.addTextChangedListener` the activity worked perfectly. I have the findViewByID, just didn't post it, because that is definetly clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use not `myEditText.getText().toString()` but `s.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

If your afterTextChanged method is really inside your onCreate method as shown, then it has the wrong scope, and it will never get called.